# IBM Cloud - Object Storage , nosuchkey

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I was followed the tutorial: 
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/static-files-cdn.html#accelerate-delivery-of-static-files-using-a-cdn

But I got the error message when I executed `curl -X "PUT" \
      "https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/$BUCKET_NAME/a-picture.png" \
     -H "x-amz-acl: public-read" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $IAM_TOKEN" \
     -H "Content-Type: image/png" \
     -T a-picture.png`

The error message shows as below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
  <Resource>/cdndata/a-picture.png</Resource>
  <RequestId>76d84ccf-4c7a-48fa-8cee-6040e0287d5b</RequestId>
  <httpStatusCode>404</httpStatusCode>
</Error>
```

What key I missed and how I generate it? Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The key refers to the object name. Are you sure the bucket exists prior to issuing this command?

Comment: Thx, but I checked my bucket_name and command line. Yes, the bucket is existing. All called cdndata.

Comment: Hi there, I just found why. But that is strange. My bucket type was standard then "Regional" and in "us-south". I got NoSuchKey error. 

Now I created another new type standard with "Cross-region". Now it's successful to upload with no error message.